# How can I make both Wifi and Mobile Data Network of iPhone working simultaneously?

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, wifi

I'm working in a camera app where I need to use cellular data while iPhone is connected to the camera device via WiFi.

But my app can't use cellular data when iPhone is connected to camera via WiFi. How can I connect to both WiFi network and mobile data network simultaneously in iOS ?

Manually I know its possible by connecting iPhone to a WiFi network and then uses its STATIC protocol instead of `DHCP` protocol.

But how can I make it user friendly by doing this task programmatically ?